# Proving nested set of intervals is a point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let ${In}_{n∈N}$ denote a family of closed intervals in R such that

i) In+1 ⊂ In for each n,

ii) ε > 0 in R implies that the length of In < ε for some n.

Show that $\cap_{n=1}^\infty In = {z}$ for some z ∈ R.

So to solve this problem I am thinkning to let In =[an,bn] and use the two A={an :n∈N} and B={bn :n∈N}. After showing that A is bounded above and B is bounded below, i have to show supA<=infB. Then somwhow I need to come up with that {a,b} ⊂ In for each n, so that $I := \cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is nonempty.
And if i use contradition to suppose that this intersection I has two distinct elements z, w. I can use ii) to obtain a contradiction.

However, I am having trouble proving the individual parts of the above framework. I am not sure how to exactly show I is nonempty and use contradition to prove z=w.

Comment: As the intersection is a set, it cannot be a real  number.  The proposition is false.  A single $\epsilon$ is inadequate.  In doesn't cut it.  Use, at least the old fashion I_n.

Answer (score 1):

A closed interval is of the form $[a,b] =\{x\in \mathbb R| a \le x \le b\}$.

Let $I_n = [a_n, b_n]$.

Note that for any $I_n = [a_n, b_n] \subset .... \subset [a_1,b_1]$ so $a_1\le a_n < b_n < b_1$.

So $A = \{a_i\}$ is bounded above (by $b_1$) and $B = \{b_i\}$ is bounded below (by $a_1$).

So $\sup A$ exist and $\inf B$ exist.

Claim 1: $\sup A = \inf B$

Claim 2: If $z = \sup A = \inf B$ then $z\in I_n$ for all $I_n$.

Claim 3: If $x \ne z$ then there is an $I_n$ so that $z \not \in I_n$.

Hence $z \in \cap_{i=1}^\infty I_n$ and if $x\ne z$ then $x\not \in \cap_{i=1}^\infty I_n$.

Conclusion:  $\cap_{i=1}^\infty I_n = \{z\}$.

Work on those claims.  I don't have time right now but I'll be back in several hours and show how to prove them.

=====

Proof of Claim 1:

It's not possible for any $a_n$ to be greater than any $b_m$. If $m < n$ then $I_n \subset I_m$ and $a_m \le a_n < b_n \le b_m$. and if $m \ge n$ then $I_m \subset I_n$ and $a_n \le a_m < b_m \le b_n$.

So for andy $b_m$ is an upper bound of $A$ and likewise every $a_m$ is a lower bound of $B$.

So for any interval $I_n$ we have $a_n \le \sup A < b_n$ and $a_n < \inf B \le b_n$.

These nested intervals have the property that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $I_n$ whose length (which would be $b_n - a_n$) is less than $\epsilon$

So we have $a_n \le \sup A < b_n$ and $a_n<\inf B \le b_n$ and $0< b_n - a_n < \epsilon$.  So $0\le |\inf B-\sup A| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

So $|\inf B - \sup A| = 0$ and $\inf B =\sup A$.

Proof of Claim 2: For an $I_n$ we have $a_n\le \sup A = \sup B = z \le b_n$ so $z\in I_n$ for all $I_n$.  So $z \in \cap I_n$.

Proof of Claim 3:  If $x \ne z$ then if we let $d = |z-x|$ we have $d > 0$.  SO there are an $I_n$ so that $b_n -a_n < d$.  As $z$ is in $I_n$ then $|z-y| < d$ for any $y\in I_n$.  But $|z-x| = d$ so $x\not \in I_n$ and so $x \not \in \cap I_n$

Comment: got it, can you show some of the proofs? thanks!